# Update data using firestore cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need help, i'm trying to update my comments collections using cloud function, but my code doesn't seem to work. My function succesfully run but doesn't update my avatarUrl when my userPhotoUrl is update

Here the whole path of the collection that i want to update : "/comments/{postId}/comments/{commentId}"

[my firestore collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v0bh.png)

```
 exports.onUpdateUser2 = functions.firestore
    .document("/users/{userId}")
    .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
      const userUpdate = change.after.data();
      const userId = context.params.userId;
      const newPhotoUrl = userUpdate.photoUrl;
      console.log("userId",userId);
      console.log("newPhotoUrl",newPhotoUrl);

    const querySnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection("comments").get();
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log("doc",doc.data());
      const postId = doc.id;
      const comments = admin.firestore().collection("comments").doc(postId).collection("comments").where("userId","==",userId).get();
      comments.forEach(doc2 => {
        return doc2.ref.update({avatarUrl: newPhotoUrl});
      });
    });
 });
```

Thank you,

**UPDATE**

I try to change the code, by using **then** to deal with these various promises but i don't really know why commentsRef.get() seem to return me empty querySnapshots, because the comments collections in my firestore database have multiple documents where in each documents there is a another comments collections where in this seconds comments collections there is a bunch of documents containing data. With this whole path i don't know how to iterate until being in the documents containing the data that i need to update. Can someone help me please ?

```
exports.onUpdateUserUpdateComments = functions.firestore
        .document("/users/{userId}")
        .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
          const userUpdate = change.after.data();
          const userId = context.params.userId;
          const newPhotoUrl = userUpdate.photoUrl;
          console.log("userId",userId);
          console.log("newPhotoUrl",newPhotoUrl);
          const commentsRef= admin.firestore().collection("comments");
          return commentsRef.get().then(querySnapshot => {
            return querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
              return admin
                 .firestore()
                 .collection("comments")
                 .doc(postId)
                 .collection("comments")
                 .where("userId", "==", userId)
                 .get()
                 .then(doc => {
                   if (doc.exists) {
                     doc.ref.update({avatarUrl: newPhotoUrl});
                   }
                   return console.log("The function has been run.");
                 });
            });
          });
     });
```

Comment: Your code isn't returning a single promise that resolves after all the asynchronous work is complete.  You're just not dealing with all these various promises correctly, both from the calls to `get()` and all the calls to `update()`.  If you're new to JavaScript, I will say that Cloud Functions is not the best place to get started learning.  Start with something simple, then work your way up in complexity.

Comment: Yes i'm new to Java Script but i really need to first work with Cloud Functions, so could you help me with this or not ? I try to change this code by doing this  by using `then`

Comment: I'm not sure I can understand your use case, your database structure looks like `/comments/{postId}/comments/{commentId}`, although your function is listening for updates on `/users/{userId}`. The naming can get somewhat confusing. Are you trying to update one single document within `comments/` sub-collection of a given `post`?

Answer (score 0):

Without trying it, it should be something like this:

```
return admin.firestore().collection("comments")
    .doc(postId)
    .where("userId", "==", userId)
    .get()
    .then(doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            doc.ref.update({avatarUrl: newPhotoUrl});
        }
        return console.log("The function has been run.");
    });
```

Regardless, following Doug Stevenson's advice, you shouldn't start learning JS in Cloud Functions, as those nested loops are a bit strange and you may lack a good starting point for learning.

Comment: Hi, I try like you did but it doesn't work because what i'm trying to do, is iterating in a comments collection with multiple documents where each documents have a another collections also called comments and where in this documents there is the data that i want to update.

Comment: So this is why i'm doing a nested loop because i don't find another way to iterate in a collections of collections, do you have any idea of how to do it ?

Comment: Check out the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.8.x/DocumentReference#getCollections) that explains about the usage of the `.listCollections()` method of the Cloud Firestore server client libraries to list all subcollections of a document reference. Please note that **retrieving a list of collections is not possible with the mobile/web client libraries**.

Comment: @sllopis it won't work cause i need to get a document first but i can't get it...

Comment: Please update your question to add your database structure @JeremyDormevil, so we can help you. Can you get a single document from your database? If so, next step is can you get a series of documents inside a collection that meet a certain condition? If so, you may want to take a look at the Collection group queries that can come in useful for your use case.